# Add a record in /etc/hosts, flushed DNS, why the domain is still not pointing to the desired IP?

Tags: macos, network, dns

Just added a record in my `/etc/hosts` but it doesn't work. I also tried to clear DNS via this way:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

When I ping that IP, it's still the IP in the real-world.

What can I do with this (so that the domain will go to the IP in my hosts file.

Comment: Can we assume you are on macOS 11 Big Sur?

Comment: Some potential solutions over here: https://superuser.com/questions/1191172/osx-sierra-hosts-file-is-ignored